# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected , validity test

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

The error occurs are IF NOT(@DATECHECK) , I am attempting to write rows to the temp table #ControlTable2 when the data in the ENTRYDATE field is an invalid date, it is stored as text

Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST_LOOP]

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @DATECHECK AS bit

select *
into #ControlTable 
from dbo.dbConvert_APPT

select TOP 1 *
into #ControlTable2 
from dbo.dbConvert_APPT

TRUNCATE TABLE #ControlTable1

declare @SHELBY_CONTROL_ID BIGint

while exists (select * from #ControlTable)
begin

    select top 1 SHELBY_CONTROL_ID
    INTO #ControlTable1
    from #ControlTable
    order by SHELBY_CONTROL_ID asc

SET @DATECHECK = (SELECT isdate(ENTRYDATE FROM #ControlTable1)

IF not( @DATECHECK)

INSERT INTO #ControlTable2
SELECT * FROM #ControlTable1

END

    delete #ControlTable
    where SHELBY_CONTROL_ID = @SHELBY_CONTROL_ID  

drop table #ControlTable
drop table #ControlTable1

SELECT * FROM  #ControlTable2

END
```

Comment: Missing Paren: `SET @DATECHECK = (SELECT isdate(ENTRYDATE FROM #ControlTable1)`
 should be: `SET @DATECHECK = (SELECT isdate(ENTRYDATE) FROM #ControlTable1)`

Answer (score 0):

`@DATECHECK` is a `BIT`, not a `BOOLEAN`. You still need to check `@DATECHECK = 1` for the parser to execute the script. Also note the missing parenthesis.